# What's wrong with this useRef hook DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

In React.js i want to implement the background color to a div element using useRef() hook but it doesn't work.

```
const cssNav = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    
    window.scrollY > 0 ? cssNav.style.backgroundColor = "white" : ""
    
  }, [])



<div ref={cssNav}> </div>
```

Comment: provide an [mre], and you're supposed to access the dom with `cssNav.current`

Comment: cssNav.current returns the current value of the useRef, not the element wanting manipulated.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to change the style of a dom element. You should probably modify a state which contains the background-color. You can add a hook to listen to the window scroll event ( it looks like some libs do it)  https://github.com/antonioru/beautiful-react-hooks/blob/master/docs/useWindowScroll.md

Comment: You need `cssNav.current.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: @jcubic Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Comment: Try adding `cssNav` as a dependency and check if it's ready.

Comment: console.log(cssNav) = { current: undefined }

Comment: I added double quote in useRef then it's worked. const cssNav = useRef("")

Comment: @RaveOnTime the value of the ref is the element you want to manipulate. atleast if you're using it correctly. which we don't know since your question basically has no useful info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The DOM element can be accessed by using **cssNav.current** .
- Generally you should pass the **null** as the initial value(to indicate no value) to the useRef() hook when manipulating DOM.

Updated Code -

```
const cssNav = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollY > 0 ? cssNav.current.style.backgroundColor = "white" : ""
  }, []);

<div ref={cssNav}> </div>
```

[Read More](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)